Why all python classes are callable by default?
It's well known that all classes in Python 3.x inherit from object base class. So, when I create an empty class like this:
class A:
  pass

I could call callable(A) or hasattr(A, '__call__') and they would show True.
>>> callable(A)
True
>>> hasattr(A, '__call__')
True

It seems obvious that the __call__ method should be in object class, but surprisingly it's not:
>>> object.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10a155940>, '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>, '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>, '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>, '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>, '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>, '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>, '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>, '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>, '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>, '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>, '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>, '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>, '__reduce_ex__': <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>, '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>, '__getstate__': <method '__getstate__' of 'object' objects>, '__subclasshook__': <method '__subclasshook__' of 'object' objects>, '__init_subclass__': <method '__init_subclass__' of 'object' objects>, '__format__': <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>, '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>, '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>, '__class__': <attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>, '__doc__': 'The base class of the class hierarchy.\n\nWhen called, it accepts no arguments and returns a new featureless\ninstance that has no instance attributes and cannot be given any.\n'})

>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']

Then the question is: why is the A class callable if it does not implement __call__? Hmm, what about type class?
>>> type(A)
<class 'type'>
>>> type.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10a155110>, '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'type' objects>, '__call__': <slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'type' objects>, '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'type' objects>, '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'type' objects>, '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'type' objects>, '__or__': <slot wrapper '__or__' of 'type' objects>, '__ror__': <slot wrapper '__ror__' of 'type' objects>, 'mro': <method 'mro' of 'type' objects>, '__subclasses__': <method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects>, '__prepare__': <method '__prepare__' of 'type' objects>, '__instancecheck__': <method '__instancecheck__' of 'type' objects>, '__subclasscheck__': <method '__subclasscheck__' of 'type' objects>, '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'type' objects>, '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'type' objects>, '__basicsize__': <member '__basicsize__' of 'type' objects>, '__itemsize__': <member '__itemsize__' of 'type' objects>, '__flags__': <member '__flags__' of 'type' objects>, '__weakrefoffset__': <member '__weakrefoffset__' of 'type' objects>, '__base__': <member '__base__' of 'type' objects>, '__dictoffset__': <member '__dictoffset__' of 'type' objects>, '__name__': <attribute '__name__' of 'type' objects>, '__qualname__': <attribute '__qualname__' of 'type' objects>, '__bases__': <attribute '__bases__' of 'type' objects>, '__mro__': <attribute '__mro__' of 'type' objects>, '__module__': <attribute '__module__' of 'type' objects>, '__abstractmethods__': <attribute '__abstractmethods__' of 'type' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects>, '__doc__': <attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects>, '__text_signature__': <attribute '__text_signature__' of 'type' objects>, '__annotations__': <attribute '__annotations__' of 'type' objects>, '__type_params__': <attribute '__type_params__' of 'type' objects>})
>>> dir(type)
['__abstractmethods__', '__annotations__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__ror__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__', '__type_params__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']

Here exactly, __call__ method is presented, does it mean that A class actually inherits from type class?
>>> isinstance(A, type)
True
>>> issubclass(A, type)
False

What the hell? Ok, probably A is class object itself of type type (for interpreter), but not the subclass of type, well let's check MRO of object, type and A:
>>> A.mro()
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> object.mro()
[<class 'object'>]
>>> type.mro(object)
[<class 'object'>]
>>> type.mro(A)
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> type.mro(type)
[<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>]

And here I am: since type class is subclass of object and A class is of type type, why MRO doesn't show type class in list? Why is A still callable if object base class doesn't have __call__ method and type class is neither superclass for A nor object?

I can't find a better explanation other than the docs for calls mentions its available on class objects, hence the definition made via the use of class is likely to be what makes this callable

@Sayse seems like literally like you said, they callable by definition, but the reason, hmm, to be able always create an instance? In this case what is responsible for this behaviour?

Its not something I really know the answer to or looked far enough into I'm afraid so can only offer what I saw in the docs above

A does not inherit from type; it (like all classes) is an instance of type.
A.__call__ would define what it means for an instance of A to be called, that is
a = A()
a()  # a.__call__() or A.__call__(a)

For A itself to be callable, you need type(A) to define __call__, which is exactly what type does.
a = A()  # a = A.__call__() or a = type.__call__(A)


But that doesn't answer why instances of type are callable?

Yes, it does. Instances of type are callable because type.__call__ is defined.

You pointed out that type is a subclass of object (true), but that doesn't mean it is an instance of object as well: type is (confusingly) an instance of type itself (similar to how object is a subclass of itself).

Btw, type is instance of object, but I understand: you mean that type create class and defines __call__ for it which body for classes by default creates the instance?

Sorry, yes. Another way to look at this is to ignore class statements, which are just a declarative syntax for hiding function calls You could define the class A with A = type('A', (), {}) to emphasize that A is an instance of type, and like instances of any type needs that type to define __call__ in order to call A.

Also worth nothing that type.__new__ doesn't do a whole lot. type.__call__ gets some instance of type as an argument, and it invokes that argument's __new__ method to get an object to return. That object is (ultimately) created by object.__new__, and type.__call__ determines whether to invoke that object's __init__ method before returning it.

according to this answer, and referenced docs

because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

not everything may be shown
if you run hasattr(object, '__call__') the result is True. Furthermore calling object like object() does create an object instead of raising a TypeError (like when running 1()) or an AttributeError

But if I create an object a = object() hasattr won't show that is has __call__ method. I mean if object is callable itself, why instances of it are not?

i believe that's how like, uh, int is callable but an instance of that type (eg. 1) is not?

Yeah, I see, that object() is __call__ and it's for instances as you said. Well, just one trick more if type is instance of object and vice versa, how this is possible, who is the "main" class?

One more addition, according the our discussion instances not necessary should be callable, but what mechanism do classes (instances of type) to be callable? Am i understand right, that __call__ method is inherited from object class and this is why all classes become callable even with empty body?

in regards to your second question: i believe so; the first one, the first one... like you did in your question, you can get the mro of an object. mro of object is object so i believe that is the root class? i honestly don't know

@aalexren maybe not a good answer to your question but i believe this post is a good read regardless concerning the isinstance(A, type) of your question
